# Fabric not using the correct key

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

In my `fabfile`, I have set `env.use_ssh_config` to `True`. Whenever I run the `fabfile`, it will get the correct `hostname` and `user` from the ssh config, but not the correct key. It will go though my keys(all stored in ~/.ssh/) at random, requiring me to enter the passphrase for all of them, till it gets to the correct key.

It's only fabric that gives me this problem. Running `scp` as a `local` command in the fabfile uses the correct key.

```
Host example
    HostName example.com
    User elssar
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_example
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Entries in my ssh config look like this.

I'm, using `Fabric 1.10.1` and `Paramiko 1.14.1`, `Python 2.7.3` and `Ubuntu 12.04`.

Edit - There is a related open issue in the fabric repository - https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1282

Edit - basic structure of my fabfile, and how I run it

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def do_something():
    run("echo test")

def setup(host):
    env.hosts = [host]


# command
fab server:hostname do_something
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the exact same versions

Comment: @goncalopp that's odd :/ What version of python are you using?

Comment: `Python 2.7.6` on debian jessie

Comment: What happens when you force `ssh` to use the same config file? I.e., `# ssh -F path/to/config example`. Do you get a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check on my setup; here is what I did to debug:

```
>>> from fabric.network import key_filenames
>>> key_filenames()
[]
>>> from fabric.state import env
>>> env.use_ssh_config = True
>>> env.host_string = 'salt-states'
>>> key_filenames()
['/Users/damien/.ssh/salt.rsa.priv']
```

update: you could update your fabfile to instrument your task:

```
from fabric.api import env, run
from fabric.network import key_filenames

def do_something_debug():
    env.use_ssh_config = True
    print key_filenames()
    run("echo test")

def server(host):
    env.hosts = [host]
```

then run the command

```
fab server:hostname do_something_debug
```

Comment: When I use the shell, it finds the correct key, but when running my fabfile, I still get the same bug.

Comment: Humm, odd. It prints the correct key file name, but still goes through keys randomly, instead of using the correct one

Comment: you could try to check `/etc/hosts` and see if your config is referencing the same host multiple times with different keys.

Comment: nothing in my `/etc/hosts` other than the default stuff